# Nest CLI plugin does not support TypeScript < v4.8

Tags: nodejs, typescript, nestjs

Estoy tratando de instalar nestjs para abrir un proyecto pero me estoy encontrando con error de version de nest CLI y typescript. Actualmente tengo instalado las siguientes versiones:

node: v18.17.1

nest: v10.1.17

nvm: v1.1.11

tsc: v5.2.2

realmente soy nuevo en el tema y cuando quiero levantar el servicio es que me aparece el error que pongo en el titulo. Agradecería cualquier ayuda para poder resolver el error.

Comment: Puede ser porque la versión de `@nestjs/cli` que has instalado de forma global es mayor que la versión con la que se hizo el proyecto. Si quieres usar la versión del proyecto puedes hacerlo usando los scripts que están en `package.json` o puedes instalar de forma global la versión anterior de `@nest/cli`.

Comment: gracias, intentare usar una version anterior de nestjs

Comment: El paquete de typescript de llama así mismo. El paquete tsc es otra cosa y debieras quitarlo (el ejecutable tsc lo disponibilizará typescript)